# Is there any Saas for content based spam detection

Tags: spam

Is there any 'non-email' spam filtering 3rd party service?

Use case:

I have ton of messages without any metadata. This last is important, so no IP , neither username nor email addresses. I have only raw messages.

The service should decide whether it is spam or ham (or just assign a spam score without an actual decision) based solely on the content.

It doesn't matter whether the service is a paid one or free to use. And it doesn't matter either which protocol the service use (however REST and SOAP preferred but not mandatory).

The service should allow ~100.000 invokation/day and should allow commercial usage.

I come accross https://plino.herokuapp.com/ and looking something like this in terms of easy of usage.